# jQuery Issue: functions won't work on newly created HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have two functions: one that creates a new `<textarea>` when a button is clicked, and a second function that performs an action when the `<textarea>` is clicked (or blurred, changed, etc.)  That second function selects elements based on a class name.  It seems that the second function only works on those matching elements that existed when the page was loaded, but it will not activate on any newly created `<textarea>` elements.  Can anyone figure out why and how to fix this?  You'll find the code below.   Thanks.  --Jake

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $(this).before("<textarea class='test'></textarea>")
})

$('.test').blur(function () {
    alert('just a test')
})
```

Comment: YALQ - Yet another live() question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The textarea you create isn't around at the time jQuery assigns the action to elements tagged with the .test class.  You'll need the live() function to make this work as desired.

```
$('.test').live('blur', function () {
    alert('just a test')
});
```

Now any element tagged with .test will automatically bind the specified function on blur no matter when it's created.

Comment: You typed your answer faster then me :P

Comment: other solutions are to use delegate() or bind the event handler to newly created elements (which may be ok if only ever adding one `textarea`)

Comment: @MLefrancois:  Doubt it, I don't type terribly quickly.  I *do* occasionally spot questions before other people do, making up for my typing.  :)

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks for teaching me a new (new to me) jQuery function.  --Jake

Comment: @Russ Cam: good call on delegate.  I always think live, I need to keep delegate in mind as well.  Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Note that this expectation of a bubbling `blur` event requires at least jQuery 1.4.2 to be cross-browser consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it directly:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $(this).before("<textarea class='test'></textarea>").prev().blur(function () {
        alert('just a test');
    });
});
```

Or place use [jQuery's `.delegate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to place a handler on the parent of `#add`.

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $(this).before("<textarea class='test'></textarea>")
}).parent().delegate('.test','blur',function() {
    alert('just a test');
});
```

This is a more efficient approach than using `.live()`.